# Is it possible to have multiple colonizable planets in your starting system?

Tags: stellaris

I ended up starting new games with a custom race continuously for about 15 minutes and only ever ended up with one colonizable planet (already colonized of course!) that was sized somewhere between 16-18. Is it possible for a random starting solar system to be generated with multiple colonizable planets? And if not, are there any ways to increase the number of colonizable planets in the starting system during gameplay?

Note that I'm not really interested in habitats as I'm more interested in having access to multiple starports for the purposes of this question, and I'm aware of Mars in Sol which is why I'm asking about random starting systems.

Comment: Fairly certain it's possible just highly unlikely because of how the game tries to balance out starts so everyone gets a few nearby colonizable planets to start. Ideally they aren't in the same system so you expand your borders anyway.

Comment: Your question seems to be a moot point now. According to the Apocalypse patch notes, systems can now only have one starbase which replaces the the planetary starports.

Comment: @Dulkan: There's still a little value in having multiple colonized planets in your core systems, since sectors still provide only up to 75% resource income. But yes, the patch has changed this (and a bunch of other questions) quite a bit.

Comment: Well, a habitat is pretty much equal in production capacity to a good planet. The main point would have been to get those extra starports for more centralized production.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point, although habitats only really come into play somewhere around the mid-late game transition (in my experience, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible- it happened to my friend. She often plays with the habitable planets setting turned up though, so that might have been a factor.

You mentioned not counting habitats but not why you needed multiple spaceports. If it's just an issue of fleet capacity, habitats do give a bonus to fleet capacity, along with the extra from their pops.

Though if you really want to add more habitable planets to your starting system, one of the results of the Horizon Signal event can do this. Follow the instructions and the end result will turn every planet in your capital system except gas giants (so molten, toxic, frozen, or barren worlds) into an empty, colonizable planet.

I won't go into the details but the event has a random chance to trigger when a Science ship enters a black hole system. Apparently you can force it by repeatedly having a ship enter and leave that system.[image: After the Worm. Time is sight, gravity is desire, everything is awesome.]

Comment: I just wanted to focus the question a bit. It's also more convenient to have multiple starports in your core systems for building ships in general. Do you know if there are restrictions on the Horizon Signal event chain or can any player empire partake in it? Also, do you know how many tomb worlds it creates? I think those 2 pieces of information are relevant for this question.

Comment: @Ellesedil I can't find anything that implies certain ethics/races are ineligible to trigger the event. Hive minds *can* do it- I specifically looked that one up. As for how many tomb worlds you get, it effects every planet (not moon) that is not a gas giant. So for Sol, it would affect Mercury, Venus, Earth, and Mars (and Pluto, if it was actually in the game).

Comment: I've got a post-worm game at the moment- I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: @ellesedil Screenshot uploaded. Magnificent, isn't it?

Comment: So, I've also triggered the Worm event a few times and on my second try, I intentionally moved my capital to a system that had something like 8+ rocky worlds, but it only converted 5 to tomb worlds in addition to the two that were already colonized. My first game also converted only 5 new planets. I suspect there's a limit of 5 new planets for it, but I'm unable to find a source that confirms it. I'm also not sure how many were moons, I'll have to load up my game and double check.

Comment: @Ellesedil Either way, that's 5 new planets in one system.

Comment: I wasn't able to trigger the Horizon Signal  playing a machine empire (assimilators specifically). I tried for several months at two different black holes in my empire.

Comment: The patchnotes of the recent mayor update (2.0 Cherryh) says that they changed the algorithm which generates home systems to make sure all empires start with similar resources. This might also have affected if there can be additional habitable planets in it. This answer might not be accurate anymore.

Comment: @Ellesedil I don't believe you can have Event Horizon event for machine empire - one of the events in chain is the biological change of your specie allowing it to live on the Tomb words. Also with the 2.0 update you can put multiple starports on one starbase speeding up the ship production (although the new "reinforce fleet" button will automatically start adding ships to your new fleet from nearby starports)